# Laravel Spark vuejs methods aren't working on events

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-spark

I've asked in IRC and slack but I can't get anyone to figure out why this isn't working.

```
//test-vue.blade.php
@extends('spark::layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div id="testing">

    <input type="text" v-model="vin">
    <button type="button" v-on:click="test">Click me</button>

</div>
@endsection

       /* resources/assets/js/boostrap.js
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Laravel Spark Components
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Here we will load the Spark components which makes up the core client
 | application. This is also a convenient spot for you to load all of
 | your components that you write while building your applications.
 */

require('./../spark-components/bootstrap');

require('./home');


var f = new Vue({

    el:'#testing',

    data: {
        items: '',
        vin: 'vdfdfa'
    },
    created: function () {
        console.log(this.vin);
        this.test();
    },

    mounted: function (){

    },

    methods: {

        test : function(){

            alert('test function called');
        },

        getDetailByVin: function(){

            console.log('testing');

            var urlData = 'http://asisauto.app:8000/test_data.json';
            // GET /someUrl
            var self = this;
            this.$http.get(urlData).then((response) => {
                // success callback
                console.log(response.body);
        }, (response) => {
                // error callback
                console.log('error');
            });

        }

    }

});
```

I've tried lots of things and can't figure out what happens.
Mounted gets called
so does 
f.text(); if I place it after the declaration.
But the button press never works. there aren't any errors in the console either.

Comment: possible to reproduce this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I have a feeling it has to do how spark is loading vuejs and its components that is messing with it. there is a root spark-app being loaded for all the components.